# Silent install of Office 2010 w/Visio and Project

Tags: installation, automated-install, visio, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-project

Is there a way to silent install Office 2010 Pro Plus with Visio 2010 Premium and Project 2010 Pro all at the same time? I've configured the msp's for each individual product and when I have the install directories all in the same folder, running setup.exe brings up a dialog asking me to choose which product to install. I want it to automatically install all three products as soon as setup.exe is launched. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered using deployment via AD using GPOs?

Comment: Yes, but it would be nice to just need to reference one install rather than three - especially for when I have to resort to manual installs. If I can't figure this out it's not the end of the world, but it would be sweet if it worked as I explained above. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an FYI to others out there, we ended up using the recommended Group Policy login script from MS and modifying it to run the three installers in one script. Not exactly what I wanted, but it works. An additional consideration is that we had set our max logon script time to be 10 minutes in GP, so if it was trying to remove an old version of Office or it was a slow computer, sometimes it would not finish and I'd have to do a manual install anyway. 95% success rate is good enough for me though :-)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602181.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can put the visio and project installations in individual folders and make the office mps file open visio after the installation is finish - then do the same vith project after visio is finished ;)